# js function not changing value

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following code.  The first time the function is called the iframe changes contents to newPage but the second time the function is called the page doesn't change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Submit</title>

<script> 
   var url = 1;

   function setURL(url){
       var win1 = "http://localhost/Audio/src/submit1.html" ;
       var win2 = "http://localhost/Audio/src/newPage.html";      

       if (url === 1){            
         document.getElementById('iframe').src=win2;
         url=2;          
       }             
       else{
           document.getElementById('iframe').src=win1; 
           url=1;
       } 
   }    
</script> 

</head> 

<body>

<iframe src="http://localhost/Audio/src/audio.html" style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>  

<iframe id="iframe" style="border:0; "   src="http://localhost/Audio/src/submit1.html"> 



</iframe>



<input type="button" value="click me 71"  onclick="setURL(url)"> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables called `url`.

The one defined as a global and the one defined as the function argument.

Your function only changes the one defined as the function argument, which isn't preserved anywhere.

If you want to modify the global one: Don't define the argument in the function definition (and don't bother passing an argument to the function).

Comment: if I don't define the argument in the function how do I change the global variable inside the function?

Comment: @DCR — With its name…

Comment: @DCR — It does not. It has a function argument with the same name that masks the global. I said you had to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

since you are passing the same name as parameter (url) you have to explicitly say which one do you want to change or change the parameter name (from url to u for instance)

Comment: i don't understand.  How do I change the global variable once inside the function?

Comment: In this case (since url variable is not binded into the Window property) you have to rename your function param to something different)